# User accepts Facebook request then autologins to my website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, autologin, invite

I have an invite friends button, that creates a facebook request to the friends you select through facebook's javascript UI mechanism.  The invitees can then click "Accept" and they'll be redirected to my facebook canvas app.

From there I want them to be redirected to my website but automatically logged in with their facebook credentials as if they clicked my Facebook Connect button and logged in that way.  How can I do this?  I guess somehow the same cookie FB Connect creates will need to be created?  My website will need to be given some kind of access_token like FB Connect returns so I can verify who the user is on my system (or create a new one).

Or is this not possible and the user will have to be simply redirected back to my website and then login through Facebook Connect even though they're already "logged in" to my facebook canvas app?

Answer (score 1):

Once the user gets redirected to your Canvas App (iframe) you are in control!
So let's assume the following:

1. The friend clicks "Accept" and get redirected to Your Canvas App
2. You receive a [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/), and check if a user_id presents (i.e he is already a website user)
3. if yes then just set your own login sessions (or whatever mechanism you use) and redirect else
4. Follow the [standard authentication flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (whether it's client side or server side)
5. If the user clicks cancel then just redirect
6. if he authorizes your app then register user (insert to DB) and follow step #3

Comment: When a friend clicks "Accept", it redirects to a page where FB asks for permission:

THIS APP WILL RECEIVE:
Your basic info
Your e-mail address
Your profile info: birthday, education history, location and work history
Friends' profile info: birthdays, education histories, locations and work histories

then after clicking "Go to App", I'm redirected to iframe app. Can we make the user automatically logged in.